# How can I retrieve count(*) values form ansible mysql_query module?

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am using ansible and `community.mysql.mysql_query` to perform some sanity on my database.

I already figured out that I need to register the output and the output holds a parameter named `query_result` that contains the returned data.

My problem is that all examples are for a standard select in which you use `param.query_result['column']` but mine has a `COUNT(*)`.

My output for this debug :

```yaml
- name: debug in db role
  debug:
    msg: |
      result : {{ first_query.query_result }}
```

is :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "result : [[{u'COUNT(*)': 16}]]\n"
}
```

Since count has * in it I cannot access it in the playbook.
Any thoughts on to how I can accomplish it and actually use this '16' count number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That was fast on my part ...

```
- name: debug in db role
  debug:
    msg: |
      result : {{ first_query.query_result[0][0]['COUNT(*)'] }}
```

Comment: You're forced to use the bracket notation for dicts when your variable/key name does not follow [ansible valid variable name convention](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). Meanwhile, an other way to solve you issue is to slightly change your query to use an alias that is valid such as `select count(*) as my_count from my_table` which then lets you address your var as either `first_query.query_result[0][0].my_count` or `first_query.query_result[0][0][''my_count']`